# line 5: [: : integer expression expected error?

Tags: macos, zsh

Hi I'm getting an integer expression expected error message with the following code:

```
#!/bin/sh

days=$(/usr/bin/uptime | /usr/bin/awk '/days/{print $3}')

if [ "$days" -ge 14 ]
then
    restart=$(/usr/bin/osascript -e 'display dialog "Your computer has not restarted in at least 14 days. Please click Restart to restart your computer or, click Defer and we will remind you tomorrow." buttons {"Restart","Defer"} default button 1 with icon POSIX file "/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/AlertStopIcon.icns" with Title "Please restart your computer!"' -e 'set browser to button returned of result')
    if [ "$restart" = 'Restart' ]
    then
        /sbin/reboot
    fi
fi
```

Any ideas why it's outputting like this:

• Executing Reboot Prompt...

• Exit code: 0

• Script results:

• /var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/T/9B9DCB41-92FA-49C8-A01D-B6CD7E3F646F: line 5: [: : integer expression expected

Comment: Use `/bin/sh -x /path/to/your/script.sh` to inspect the commands that are actually run.

Comment: What if `"$days"` is an empty string? Then it's not an integer value. Set a default value for the variable.

Comment: Also you've tagged your question with bash, but macOS uses zsh by default now. If you want to ensure you're always using bash, change your shebang accordingly.

Comment: Add the line `printf 'days = "%s"\n' "$days"` just before the `if` statement to inspect the value of the `days` variable.

Comment: @miken32, `#!/bin/sh` won't be zsh except in `sh` emulation mode, where it follows the POSIX sh standard more closely than bash does (ironically, given how gratuitously noncompliant zsh is otherwise). But yes, this question certainly shouldn't be tagged `bash` in any event unless the OP changes their shebang so it actually uses bash.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin, I would suggest `set -x` or starting the script with `#!/bin/sh -x` instead: `printf 'var=%s\n' "$var"` doesn't do any good to make hidden characters readable, so it's not as effective as a good `set -x` implementation at showing variables' true values in a human-readable way.

Answer (score 1):

What if the uptime output does not include the word `days`?

Use a default value (zero) if the `days` variable is empty.

```bash
if [ "${days:-0}" -ge 14 ]
```